# There are tan and gray pieces

Tags: set-identification

And the two flame pieces, with smaller bag inside.[image]

Comment: Indeed there are. What's your question though?

Answer (score 6):

I started looking at sets containing a 6L technic axle in red, and I soon came across [60216-1 Downtown Fire Brigade](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60216-1) :

[image: set 60216]

Your bag looks like it contains the main building there - 1x6x5 tan panels, 1x4 bricks with brick pattern, 1x6x1 grey arches, they're all in there.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (because there is no question)